# Failed to go to Google Api Credentials

Tags: android, google-api-console

I am incorporating google plus sign in my app and for that i have created client keys in Google API console but suddenly  I don't know what happened,I am unable to view the credential page and when ever i click the credentials it shows:-

Error

```
 You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page.
```

Comment: I got same error few days back, try to open account on other system.

Comment: try it in private window of your browser

Comment: @Rajsundar-Still the same issue.

Comment: Please check your proxy and try it in incognito window I have faced the same issue but now it's working for me in incogniton window

Comment: @Rajsundar_I tried it in incognito mood tho,still its not working

Comment: @Rajsundar--now suddenly its working in incognito,While it was not working yesterday for the same.I think there is something else.Its been so weird.